# Yii2 SQLSTATE[22003] during insert

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

in my yii2 advanced template, i get the exception SQLSTATE[22003] of the database.

with this error message:

> SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'created_at' at row 1
>   The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `email`, `password_hash`, `auth_key`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('test', 'test@email.it', 'someval', 'someval', 10, NOW(), NOW())

i checked the fields that cause this exception (i've assumed that are the date fields created_at and updated_at) and they're both int(20).

in the model i've timestamp behavior:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
            ],
            'value' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()')
        ],
    ];
}
```

I really don't know what cause this error. This is the standard registration functionality inserted in the yii2 advanced template.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value of `NOW()` is not integer its something like `2016-06-13 13:36:28` which is not in integer, so change your table as timestamp,datetime or varchar

```
ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `created_at` `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `updated_at` `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

And use quote around `NOW()`

Comment: Hi Rishi thanks for your answer. I'll give now a try

Comment: Glad to help you :)